# It it possible to integrate OWA and OpenID?

Tags: authentication, outlook, openid, outlook-web-app

Is it possible to integrate OWA (Outlook Web Access) and OpenID with a standard, existing component? If not, is it theoretically possible with a straightforward integration plugin (most probably using dotnetopenid)? Any hints on necessary API-s, components, technologies etc would be useful.